# Removing colour bands in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geotiff-tiff

How do I remove unwanted colour from the palette from a Raster via the  PyQGIS API? For example, remove black from the palette. It works manually within Layer Properties -> Symbology -> Band Rendering -> Paletted.

I have looked in 3.10 API docs but can't see how this is done.

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsPalLayerSettings.html

Comment: What do you mean by 'black (0)'?

Comment: I updated the question, i just mean remove the colour black from the palette.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

- Get palette values

  ```
  classes = layer.renderer().classes()
  ```
- Remove any class

  ```
  del classes[0] # removes the first item
  ```
- Set layer renderer

  ```
  renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(provider, band, classes)
  layer.setRenderer(renderer)
  ```

Minimal sample code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

renderer = layer.renderer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()
band = renderer.band()    
classes = renderer.classes()
del classes[0]  # remove the first color

renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(provider, band, classes)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works